# How can I find out if a matrix is an identity matrix using SML NJ?

Tags: matrix, sml, pseudocode

I am new to this language and I find this a bit confusing. Can you help me with this please?
I just have a pseudocode so far. Will you help with the syntax please?

The each row of the matrix would be a list and the argument would be list of lists

```
function (list of lists) = 
    if (matrix is null) then
        false
    else if (unit matrix with element 1) then
        true
    else
        add all the lists and get a list with the lenght of number of lists
        check if each element is 2
        if (2) then
            true
        else false
```

Comment: May be back later in the day (European time) for an answer, but for now, what about using an appropriate type for matrix? Two‑dimensional array could be a match: [The Array2 structure](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array2.html). Then check the matrix is a square prior to anything.

Comment: write a function for the Kronecker delta: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta and check whether M_i,j equals kronecker(i,j) for all i,j

Answer (score 0):

Lists of lists are not optimal for dealing with matrices in SML, but it is still a good exercise to write a function for checking if a list of lists is an identity matrix.

A recursive approach is natural. In the following picture:

[image]

Note that:

1. The first element of the first row is a 1
2. The rest of that row is all 0
3. The rest of the first column is all 0
4. The rest of the matrix (below and to the right of the shaded region) is itself an identity matrix.

As a preliminary, write a function which tests if a list is all 0. You could use the standard basis function `all` to do so, though it is easy enough to roll your own:

```
fun all_zeros [] = true
|   all_zeros (x::xs) = x = 0 andalso all_zeros xs
```

The main function checks the 4 points given above. Some care must be given to various basis cases. The empty list is not an identity matrix. Nor is a list of empty lists. This last case is easy to overlook, but if you pass the function a matrix which has more rows than columns you run out of columns before rows. I am mapping `hd` across the bottom rows to extract the rest of column 1 (below the element in the upper left) and am mapping `tl` across the bottom rows to get the lower right part of the matrix to feed back into the function recursively. This might produce a nonempty lists of empty lists, so that must be checked:

```
fun id_matrix [] = false
|   id_matrix (row::[]) = (row = [1])
|   id_matrix ([]::rows) = false
|   id_matrix (row::rows) = 
    let
       val x :: xs = row
    in
       x = 1 andalso 
       all_zeros(xs) andalso 
       all_zeros(map hd rows) andalso 
       id_matrix(map tl rows)
    end
```

As a final remark -- my code assumes that the lists of lists represents a valid array and merely checks if it is the identity. Passing it a jagged array rather than a matrix could crash it. It would be easy enough to add a check, though it would make the code more cumbersome.

Comment: I know this is an old question but I thought it would be fun to find some old but interesting unanswered questions in some of my favorite SO tags.